# Call to a templated member function that takes an object and a member function in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I will try to explain my problem. I want to create an object, here called monitor, that protects the access to any function we pass to it using a mutex.

```
template <typename O, typename F>
bool Monitor::captureData(O& f_captureObject, F f_captureFunction)
{
    // Lock data access
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex);

    // Capture data and check if it is ready
    if ((f_captureObject.*f_captureFunction)() == true)
    {
        // If data is ready ...

        // Set data flag to ready
        m_isReady = true;

        // Notify if processing thread is waiting
        m_conditionVariable.notify_one();
    }
    else
    {
        // If data is not ready ...

        // Set data flag to not ready
        m_isReady = false;
    }

    // Return grab state
    return !m_isReady;
}
```

The monitor will we be created on other object called synchronizer, and there I call to the templated function with:

```
void Synchronizer::runSimulationCamera()
{
...
    m_monitorCamera.captureData<Bumblebee, bool (Bumblebee::*)()>(m_camera, &Bumblebee::capture);
...
}
```

Where Bumblebee is the object that runs the opearation that I want to protect.

```
bool Bumblebee::capture()
{
...
}
```

Here the original link error:

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: bool __cdecl Monitor::captureData<class Bumblebee,bool (__cdecl Bumblebee::*)(void)>(class Bumblebee &,bool (__cdecl Bumblebee::*)(void))" (??$captureData@VBumblebee@@P81@EAA_NXZ@Monitor@@QEAA_NAEAVBumblebee@@P81@EAA_NXZ@Z) occupancyMap
```

Can anyone tell me what that message error really means? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This error means that the linker thinks the compiler didn't actually generate the code for this function with the template parameters you used, so it says "unresolved symbol". Did you use `extern template` in your code? That can cause this error.

Comment: Also - is `occupancyMap` something in your code? If so, please attach the relevant parts!

Comment: It can't find the template instance. Maybe the template function isn't in the header file.

Comment: occupancyMap is the name of the project @unddoch